# Entity Framework code first decimal precision in data migration

Tags: sql-server, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I've added a decimal property to an EF6 code first class and generated the migration class for it. This always seems to generate a migration to make a precision (18,2) decimal. So before actually applying the migration I've changed the migration to make a decimal(19,12) instead like so:

```
AddColumn("dbo.cv_location", "latitude", c => c.Decimal(precision: 19, scale: 12));
AddColumn("dbo.cv_location", "longitude",c => c.Decimal(precision: 19, scale: 12));
```

Now when updating the database the added column will have the correct precision and scale in the database. The insert/update queries created by EF do not have the correct values however. Below is an example of a created query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[cv_location]
SET [modify_date] = @0, [latitude] = @1, [longitude] = @2
WHERE (([location_id] = @3) AND ([timestamp] = @4))
SELECT [timestamp]
FROM [dbo].[cv_location]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [location_id] = @3',
      N'
      @0 datetime2(7),
      @1 decimal(18,2),
      @2 decimal(18,2),
      @3 int,
      @4 binary(8)',
      @0='2014-04-16 09:58:20.9228016',
      @1=52.38,
      @2=5.18,
      @3=45,
      @4=0x000000000000FC05
```

Note how the decimal parameters are both decimal(18,2) which obviously causes me to lose information when inserting/updating.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this just a bug in EF6?

Thanks in advance.